# FTP via PhoneGap

Tags: android, ftp, cordova

I would like to develop an FTP file system using PhoneGap.

Essentially i would like the user to be able to have a list of sites they can connect to and get the whole root directory for viewing and changing file names.

I can do this process with C# and .NET languages but have no knowledge on achieving this with PhoneGap.

Are there specific library's i could use?
Will i have to develop everything from scratch?
Is it possible to mix Native with PhoneGap?
What kind of security will i be looking at achieving here?

If you could answer one or all of these questions that is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very easy way of achieving what you want in android is falling back to Native java code and use the [Apache FTPClient class](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html).

There is a very good easy to read plugin [here](https://github.com/macdonst/FtpClient/tree/master/v2.2.0). You can get it and take a look on how it works. Basically it uses the FTP client class and it has two built in methods to `Upload` a file and to `Download` a file from the server.

It's again dead easy to expand the `Execute` method to perform other actions like `Rename` and `Delete` :

Java Code:

```
public boolean execute (...) { 

       ...
       if (action.equals("get")) {
            get(filename, url);
        }
        else if (action.equals("put")) {
            put(filename, url);
        }
        else if (action.equals("delete")){
           delete(filename,url);
        } else if (action.equals("rename")){
           rename(filename,url);
        }
        ...
 } 

private void delete(String filename, URL url) throws IOException {
    FTPClient f = setup(url);
    f.deleteFile(extractFileName(url));
    teardown(f);
}

private void rename(String newFilename, URL url) throws IOException {
        FTPClient f = setup(url);    
        f.rename(extractFileName(url),newFilename);
        buffOut.flush();
        buffOut.close();
        teardown(f);
    }
```

And add these methods too on the javascript layer

```
FtpClient.prototype.delete = function(url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
         return exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "FtpClient", "get", [" ", url]);
    };
   FtpClient.prototype.rename = function(newFilename, url, successCallback, errorCallback) {
         return exec(successCallback, errorCallback, "FtpClient", "get", [newFilename, url]);
    };
```

If you need instructions on how to use a phonegap plugin there is a good guide [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_plugin-development_android_index.md.html#Developing%20a%20Plugin%20on%20Android). Basically you need to do the follwowing:

- Write your java code
- Write your javascript code and using the exec Method call the native layer
- Add your plugin to res/xml/config

Specifically for the plugin I posted above, in the github readme you can see [the instructions on how to install that plugin](https://github.com/macdonst/FtpClient).